# My IF statement is not able to detect vairable differences

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following code in PLSQL. 
I'm not sure why the IF statement is not firing off.
The curr_app and the_app variables are different however the outtput of the dbms inside of the if statement is never firing off.

```
DECLARE
the_app VARCHAR2(200);
curr_app VARCHAR2(200);

BEGIN
  the_app :='';
  curr_app :='';
  FOR i IN
  (SELECT APP_NAME,CONTACT_TYPE,CONTACT_DEPT,CONTACT_VALUE
  FROM CMSv2.CMS_APPLICATIONS CMSA
  LEFT JOIN CMSV2.CMS_APP_CONTACTS CMSAC
  ON CMSa.APP_NAME = CMSAC.CONTACT_APP and (CMSAC.END_DT IS NULL and CMSAC.RET_DT IS NULL)
  WHERE CMSA.END_DT IS NULL
  AND CMSA.RET_DT IS NULL ORDER BY APP_NAME
  )
  LOOP
  curr_app := i.APP_NAME;
  dbms_output.put_line('curr_app' || curr_app);
  dbms_output.put_line('the_app' || the_app);
  IF the_app<>curr_app THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('doservers for' || i.APP_NAME);
  END IF;
  dbms_output.put_line(i.APP_NAME);

  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: When `''` is assigned to a variable it becomes a zero length string. Oracle treats zero length string as `NULL`. Any comparison to NULL results to UNKNOWN. That's why, in your situation, the `if` condition is never `true`.

Comment: FYI - You can initialize the variables at the time they are declared like this: `the_app VARCHAR2(200) := '';`

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle an empty string is the equivalent of `NULL`.

The truth table for comparing the difference between `BOOLEAN`s is:

```
A <> B | TRUE  | FALSE | NULL
-------+-------+-------+-------
TRUE   | FALSE | TRUE  | NULL
FALSE  | TRUE  | FALSE | NULL
NULL   | NULL  | NULL  | NULL
```

So your `IF` condition can be reduced to:

```
IF( something <> NULL ) THEN ...
```

Which will never be true.